# React Render with Hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am following some tutorial and I am confused regarding how things render when using HOC

So firstly, I guess props flow from parent to child and is one directional?

Here we created two HOC, The **Aux** and **withclass**

The Aux doesn't do anything special besides passing props.children

```
const aux = (props) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

The withClass HOC function takes two parameter App and className..

```
const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
   return class extends Component {
       render () {
           return (
               <div className={className}>
                   <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
               </div>
           )
       }
   }
```

And our App.js which is passed as an argument looks like this

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

import classes from './App.css';
import Persons from '../components/Persons/Persons';
import Cockpit from '../components/Cockpit/Cockpit';
import Aux from '../hoc/Aux';
import withClass from '../hoc/withClass';

class App extends PureComponent {
//something 
  render () {
if ( this.state.showPersons ) {
  persons = <Persons
    persons={this.state.persons}
    clicked={this.deletePersonHandler}
    changed={this.nameChangedHandler} />;
}

return (
  <Aux>
    <button onClick={() => { this.setState( { showPersons: true } ) }}>Show Persons</button>
    <Cockpit
      appTitle={this.props.title}
      showPersons={this.state.showPersons}
      persons={this.state.persons}
      clicked={this.togglePersonsHandler} />
    {persons}
  </Aux>
);

  }
}

export default withClass( App, classes.App );
```

**[Question]** So based on the above code if someone can please explain what exactly happens, the way things execute and render?

Secondly, We used **`{...this.props}` in our withClass HOC** because according to the instructor they are wrapped and hence our other component, even though they receive prop they can't pass them. Can someone explain this with an example? Also `{...this.props}` creates copy of all the props? and shouldn't it be like  `<WrappedComponent = {...this.props} />` instead of  `<WrappedComponent {...this.props} />`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, what is a HOC?

A HOC is a [Higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). This means it is a function that takes as its first argument a component and then returns a component.

From this definition you can immediately see that:

- withClass is an HOC
- Aux is *not* an HOC

Aux is a functional component. Classic React components are created by defining a class that inherits from React.Component. A newer, simpler way of defining components is to create functions that simply accept `props` as the first parameter and return what should be rendered.

> So based on the above code if someone can please explain what exactly happens, the way things execute and render?

Well, let's look at `App` just as a component. We have `withClass` and `App` and you're exporting `withClass(App, classes.App)`. What would it look like if, instead of using an HOC we used a functional component? It'd look like this:

```
const AppWithClass = props =>
  <div className={classes.App}>
    <App/>
  </div>
```

In this case, *no props are passed to App*. So with this use-case, there is no need to pass `props` through by writing `{...props}`. And you'd then simply export AppWithClass.

But usually you write HOCs to be reusable. In that case, you don't know if the component that will be passed to your HOC will receive props or not. For that reason, you want the component you create to take any `props` passed to it and to *pass them through* to the wrapped component.

Let's say you have a `Button` component that takes a parameter `colour`. You'd typically use it like this:

```
<Button colour="red"/>
```

But you want to wrap it with a `div` and add a class to that `div`. So you use `withClass` as follows:

```
const ButtonWithClass = withClass(Button, "button-class");
```

Now you can use `Button` as follows:

```
<ButtonWithClass colour="red"/>
```

And really what you'll get is:

```
<div className="button-class">
  <Button colour="red"/>
</div>
```

If you did not write `{...this.props}` when rendering `WrappedComponent` in your `withClass` HOC, then `colour` would not get passed through to `Button`. In your HOC, `WrappedComponent` is equal to `Button` in the above case.

The syntax `{...this.props}` is a combination of the [Object literal spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) and JSX's own behaviour. The Object spread syntax used in this way means the keys of the given object will become the prop names and the values will become their respective values. So when you write `{...{ colour: 'red' }}` you're asking JSX to get props from an object that you define inline.

To continue with the above example:

```
<ButtonWithClass colour="red"/>
```

Inside `withClass` this becomes equivalent to:

```
const WrappedComponent = Button;
return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
```

And here `this.props` equals `{ colour: 'red' }`. So the above becomes:

```
const WrappedComponent = Button;
return <WrappedComponent {...{ colour: 'red' }}/>;
```

Which then becomes:

```
const WrappedComponent = Button;
return <WrappedComponent colour="red"/>;
```

I hope that helps!