# Javascript Import/Export statement

Tags: javascript

In javascript, will they both be similar (Part 1 and Part 2)?

**[Part 1]**

```
const sething = () => {
  //Something
}

const sething1 = () => {
  //Something 
}
```

**[Part 2]**

```
const sething = () => {
  //Something 
}

export default sething
```

and then

```
import sething from /location 

const sething1 = () => {
  //Something 
}
```

If they both aren't similar can someone tell me why not? and suggest any articles to read.

Also what will be the result if we do something like this for classes?

Comment: Similar? Yes. Equal? No.

Comment: Can you please what you mean by **they won't be equal in details** in the answer section

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. To avoid it getting flagged as such, can you please give us more details on exactly what differences you're curious about?

Comment: @Hamms I am trying to connect dots for this question (which for some reason went unanswered) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396413/react-render-with-hoc

Comment: @Luca Can you please what you mean by they **won't be equal** in details in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are essentially doing the same.

In the first example you have two functions that are not `===` in one file, and in the second example you are defining two functions, that are also not `===`, only difference being, that you imported one of them.

What I meant with

> Similar? Yes. Equal? No.

is that they are obviously not the same thing. Import/Export has nowhere near the performance of just having the two functions in one file and it's simply more code.

Both would function the same, though there are also advantages to defining functions in files you later import.

You can use them multiple times, if you need that and you can then easily change it in one place instead of having to change the function everywhere. Otherwise this would be [Code Duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code).

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you're asking: "Is Part 1 equivalent to Part 2" where Part 2 defines `sething` in a separate file and then imports it into the same scope as `sething1`.

My answer is:

- There are some ways that these are equivalent
- There are some ways that these are different

## How are they equivalent?

In both **Part 1** and **Part 2**, you end up with `sething` and `sething1` defined as constants. If all you're concerned about is the behaviour of your application then for the most part I'd treat these as equivalent.

## How are they different?

1. If you re-use `sething` somewhere else, you'll simple be able to import it there. You can do that in **Part 2** but not without refactoring or repeating yourself in **Part 1**. Or perhaps having one massive file.
2. If you wish to refactor the name `sething`, it'll be easier in **Part 1** than in **Part 2**. In **Part 2** most IDEs will change the imported name without changing the name of the constant inside the imported file. If it's used anywhere else, those uses will not be renamed. This can easily be fixed by using a named export instead of a default export.

I hope that helps and answers your question!